# Combine two different array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array data that I want to combine into one array, the first array contain only data of date and id, the second array contain name and id.

```
    temp_data:[
      0:{
        id:"1"
        date:"2017-11-07"
      }
      1:{
        id:"1"
        date:"2017-11-08"
      }
      2:{
        id:"2"
        date:"2017-11-07"
      }
      3:{
        id:"2"
        date:"2017-11-08"
      }
] 

name:[
      0:{
       id:"1"
       name:"Pervies, Peter"
      }
      1:{
       id:"2"
       name:"Ming, Edmund"
      }
]
```

I want the data to be look like this:

```
    data:[
    0:{
     id:"1"
     name:"Pervies, Peter"
     details:[
        {date:"2017-11-07"},
        {date:"2017-11-08"}
     ]
    }
    1:{
     id:"2"
     name:"Ming, Edmund"
     details:[
        {date:"2017-11-07"},
        {date:"2017-11-08"}
     ]
    }
]
```

I have try the code below to combine the two array,it works but not in the way I expect.

```
  let len = temp_data.length;
    let leng = name.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < leng; ++i) {
            for (let x = 0; x < len; ++x) {
                if (name[i].id == temp_data[x].id) { 
                    let id = name[i].id;
                    let details = temp_data[x];
                    data.push({id,details})
                }
            }
        }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------

       let dat = temp_data,
       hash = Object.create(null),
       result = [];

   dat.forEach(function (o) {
        if (!hash[o.id]) {
         hash[o.id] = [];
         result.push(hash[o.id]);
        }
          hash[o.id].push(o);
    });

        data = result;
```

can you help me with this?

Comment: Can you include the array code instead of image?

Comment: just a second :)

Comment: You can't combine those arrays as they have syntax errors making them invalid. Array does not store key:value pairs like in your example.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I updated it ...

Comment: Please update the question for the output for the given input? I am not able to figure out the structure of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and iterate both array only once.

```js
var data = [{ id: "1", date: "2017-11-07" }, { id: "1", date: "2017-11-08" }, { id: "2", date: "2017-11-07" }, { id: "2", date: "2017-11-08" }],
    names = [{ id: "1", name: "Pervies, Peter" }, { id: "2", name: "Ming, Edmund" }],
    map = new Map,
    result = names.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name, details: map.set(id, []).get(id) }));

data.forEach(({ id, date }) => map.get(id).push({ date }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your output does not match the OP's. I believe. you are missing the `id`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this:

1. Create an empty object/hash {id: {id: id, name: name, details: []}}.
2. Loop through the name array, and populate the hash with an object with id and name.
3. Loop through the temp_data array, and populate/update the hash with date values. (You'll need to check if the element already contains the details member. If not, create one. And, append the new date.)
4. Convert the values of the hash into an array. (`Object.values()`)

Nothing fancy, but this will do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you had errors in your array, arrays do not store `key:value` pairs like I said in the comments, inside objects you need `,` to separate array entries and you need `,` to separate properties inside the actual objects.

When you assign an array to a variable you do not use `:` but `=` otherwise you'll get syntax errors.

You can use a simple two way for loop like below;

```
var newArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
    var newObj = name[i];
  newObj.details = [];
    var id = name[i].id;

  for(var j = 0; j < temp_data.length; j++){
    if(id == temp_data[j].id){
        newObj.details.push({date : temp_data[j].date});
    }
  }

  newArray.push(newObj);
}
```

Which will generate your desired output in a simple, old fashion way. See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6a60qj33/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

First group your `temp_data` array items by `id` property:

```
temp_data.forEach(function(d) {
  if (!results.some(function(item) {
      return item.id == d.id;
    })) {
    let mixed = {};
    mixed.id = d.id;
    (mixed.details = mixed.details || []).push({
      "date": d.date
    });
    results.push(mixed);
  } else {
    results.find(function(r) {
      return r.id == d.id;
    }).details.push({
      "date": d.date
    });
  }
});
```

Then add the `name` property to each relevant item in your `results` array, from `names` array:

```
results.forEach(function(r) {
  if (names.some(function(n) {
      return n.id == r.id;
    })) {
    r.name = names.find(function(name) {
      return name.id == r.id;
    }).name;
  }
});
```

**Explanation:**

- I used `.forEach()` to loop over the merged array elements, and for
  each `item`:
- I used `.some()`method to check over the existence of an item with
  the same `id` in the array.
- Then used `.find()`to get this object if it exists, and update it
  with relevant data.

**Demo:**

```js
const temp_data = [{
    id: "1",
    date: "2017-11-07"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    date: "2017-11-08"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    date: "2017-11-07"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    date: "2017-11-08"
  }
];

const names = [{
  id: "1",
  name: "Pervies, Peter"
}, {
  id: "2",
  name: "Ming, Edmund"
}];

var results = [];

//First group your first array objects by id

temp_data.forEach(function(d) {
  if (!results.some(function(item) {
      return item.id == d.id;
    })) {
    let mixed = {};
    mixed.id = d.id;
    (mixed.details = mixed.details || []).push({
      "date": d.date
    });
    results.push(mixed);
  } else {
    results.find(function(r) {
      return r.id == d.id;
    }).details.push({
      "date": d.date
    });
  }
});

results.forEach(function(r) {
  if (names.some(function(n) {
      return n.id == r.id;
    })) {
    r.name = names.find(function(name) {
      return name.id == r.id;
    }).name;
  }
});
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp_date = [{"id": "1", "date": "2017-11-07"}, {"id": "1", "date": "2017-11-08"}, {"id": "2", "date": "2017-11-07"}, {"id": "2", "date": "2017-11-08"}];
var name = [{"id": "1", "name": "Pervies, Peter"}, {"id": "2", "name": "Ming, Edmund"}];
var data = []
for(var i = 0; i < name.length; i++ ){
  data.push({"id": name[i].id, "name": name[i].name, "details": []});
  for(var j = 0; j < temp_date.length; j++){
    if(name[i].id === temp_date[j].id){
      data[i].details.push({"date": temp_date[j].date});
    }
  }
}
```

Need to correct temp_date and name array and apply the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use undescore library for this task:

```
let _ = require ('underscore');

let  temp_data =[
      {
        id:"1",
        date:"2017-11-07"
      },
      {
        id:"1",
        date:"2017-11-08"
      },
      {
        id:"2",
        date:"2017-11-07"
      },
      {
        id:"2",
        date:"2017-11-08"
      }
] ;

let name = [
      {
       id:"1",
       name:"Pervies, Peter"
      },
      {
       id:"2",
       name:"Ming, Edmund"
      }
];

temp_data = temp_data.concat(name);

let groupedTempData = _.groupBy(temp_data,function(item){
        return item.id;
});

let result = [];

_.each(groupedTempData,function(item){

    let obj = {};
    obj.details =[];

    _.each(item,function(data){
        if(data.name){
            obj.name = data.name;
        }
        if(data.date){
            obj.details.push({date:data.date});
        }
    });
    obj.id = item[0].id;

    result.push(obj);

});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```